# Make a bitnami wordpress stack in virtual box host a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, networking, debian, virtualbox, bitnami

I have installed the follows

1. virtual box in my windows 10 home pc
2. the virtual box has a wordpress site stack VM whose image was from bitnami's site
3. I set up network as Bridged networking and the adapter is my realtek WLAN

I have installed wordpress and made my all required plugins in it

What do I actually need?

1. I am able to login using 192 168.43.xx
2. I want to use that virtual machine to host the site and I want to link the site to domain using *A* record
   I want the Virtual machine to host not only to local network which is 192.168.xx.xx
   I want to be available throughout internet

I have also tried using my laptop's IP and it does not work

Please help me regarding it. Iam a newbie..  so please comment if any queries (not too techie)

Answer (score 2):

If you configured the network adapter as Bridged adapter, you should be able to access the WordPress machine from another computer in the same network by using the private IP address of the VM (192 168.43.xx). If you want to access the application from outside your network, you will need to configure the port forwarding rules in your router to redirect the incoming requests to the VM (publicIP:80 -> virtualmachineIP:80). [This online site](https://portforward.com/) has a lot of information about how to configure this in different routers.

Comment: I would like to say that I am using mobile personal hotspot...

Comment: Which network type of virtual box should I use?

Comment: My need is as follows: I need my site not only in the local network, but for the whole network

Comment: I'm not really sure if you can configure the port forwarding using the mobile hotspot. You will need to check you phone's settings to see if that's possible.

Comment: howto edit the files from host IDE? Is FTP a good option?

Comment: Hi @SL5net, it's much easier if you use the command line and a command line editor like vim, emacs or nano. You can find useful information in the web regarding how to use them

Comment: I have the VM's network as bridged and the IP is 192.168.0.103. I have configured forwarding using virtual servers on router as "Service port=80", "internal port=80", IP=192.168.0.103. HOw can i access the site that is being served in 192.168.0.103 in other networks?

Comment: Hi @Karthik, if you configure the port forwarding settings in your router, you can access your application using the public IP of your internet connection. There are websites that provide you with that information, you will just need to paste that public IP in the address bar of your browser.